# What does `args` in Linux command `ps ao args` means exactly?

Tags: linux

In the man page of `ps`, I found that `-a` means:

> Select all processes except both session leaders (see getsid(2)) and
>   processes not associated with a terminal.

and `-o` means

> User-defined format.  format is a single argument in the form of a blank-separated or comma-separated list, which offers a way to specify individual output columns.  The recognized keywords are described in the STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS section below. Headers may be renamed (ps -o pid,ruser=RealUser -o comm=Command) as desired.  If all column headers are empty (ps -o pid=-o comm=) then the header line will not be output.  Column width will increase as needed for wide headers; this may be used to widen up columns such as WCHAN (ps -o pid,wchan=WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN -o comm).  Explicit width control (ps opid,wchan:42,cmd) is offered too.  The behavior of ps -o pid=X,comm=Y varies with personality; output may be one column named "X,comm=Y" or two columns named "X" and "Y".  Use multiple -o options when in doubt.  Use the PS_FORMAT environment variable to specify a default as desired; DefSysV and DefBSD are macros that may be used to choose the default UNIX or BSD columns.

But what does the `args` means in this command?

Note the `args` is not a placeholder for anything else, just 4 chars: `a`+`r`+`g`+`s`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args` is one of the options to the `-o` flag, meaning "display the command with all of its arguments as a string. From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#STANDARD_FORMAT_SPECIFIERS):

```
   args        COMMAND   command with all its arguments as a string.
                         Modifications to the arguments may be shown.
                         The output in this column may contain spaces.
                         A process marked <defunct> is partly dead,
                         waiting to be fully destroyed by its parent.
                         Sometimes the process args will be unavailable;
                         when this happens, ps will instead print the
                         executable name in brackets.  ...
```